# How to read a json file that is embedded as part of an MSI package and populate the values in a combo box in the MSI UI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I am developing an MSI installer using Wixsharp.Net and need to update the combo box in the custom managed UI with the data from (Serialized) JSON configuration file.

Request to throw some light on how to implement this using .NET and Wixsharp

Comment: How is it embedded? In the Binary table?

Comment: It is embedded as a zip file, along with few other resources that will be installed to filesystem during the actual install phase

Comment: how is the zip file embedded?  in the binary table?  as a component/file?

Comment: It's embedded as a component.